# If the the readers of every kind of BOOKS (scientific, tech, humanistic etc) finds something to clarify; how to find help or even to contact authors?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I think, many of us, as students or researchers or even as simple intersted persons, during reading of Scientific, technical or humanistic books, (academical or not academical) find often something not clear. So I suggest to create a section where is possible to ask questions related to part of books which create doubt or curiosity to the people reading. Even  if it's possible to find someone who know how contacting the authors to ask directly...

Comment: P.S. downvoting on meta signifies "I don't think we should implement this suggestion", not "this is a bad question." It's a perfectly good question, just an unpopular suggestion :)

Answer (score 6):

That's not what *this* site is about; we're about the culture, ethics, procedures, etiquette, etc of academia. *Not* about the contents of every field of study.

In general, questions about something that is unclear in a book about a specific topic may be posed on the Stack Exchange site for that topic. For example, a question about something that is unclear in a mathematics book may be suitable on [Mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com), about something that is unclear in a political science book on [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/),  etc. The subject-specific sites have users who are subject matter experts, who answer questions about their own field on the site about their field.